# Pass XYZ values into MS Flight Sim 2004

Tags: python, virtualization

I am planning on using my Android device's gyroscope readings and using these to control your aircraft within flight sim. Using Python, I am currently passing a continuous flow of XYZ readings from the gyroscope to my PC using UDP. I would like to know whether there is a way to interface with Flight Sim to use these values to control the aircraft.

Microsoft has an API called [SimConnect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc526983.aspx), but I am not sure if you can pass values into flight sim. Also, I have heard of [FSUIPC](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwilzYb-6e_JAhVBUhoKHRROB1cQFggfMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.schiratti.com%2Fdowson.html&usg=AFQjCNFY3FC3PQ0t-QCQGBKSW34FWul0Lg&sig2=St_2AAZWfcKoXFSGMbbkGw&bvm=bv.110151844,d.ZWU), but I would have no idea where to start.

Is it possible to pass XYZ values into MS Flight Sim, maybe as a virtual controller of some kind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement a Virtual Human Interface Device (VHID).  Docs for doing that in Windows 10 are here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn925056(v=vs.85).aspx

If you need to support older versions of Windows, you might need to use a different API, [UMDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-Mode_Driver_Framework).  I think one useful example for that might be this one: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/hid/vhidmini2 though do note it is for the "V2" API which is for Windows 8 and later.  You can go all the way back to Windows XP if you write to UMDF V1.

There is also a third-party library, vJoy, which seems to be designed for what you're trying to do: http://vjoystick.sourceforge.net/site/